# Google heatmap not showing data points properly

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, pheatmap

I am facing a strange problem with google heatmap. Heatmap shows less datapoints on increasing number of coordinates in heatmap data.
For 333 coordinates, heatmap shows datapoints like:
[image]

And for 9885 coordinates :
[image]

As you can see for 333 coordinates there are more datapoints than 9885 coordinates. But it should show more datapoints for large data.
My code:

```js
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('bcak_track_map'), {
    zoom:19,
    center:{lat:parseFloat(flat), lng:parseFloat(flon)},
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
});
map.setTilt(45);

var heatMapBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

var markerCount = 0;
$.each(marker_points, function (key, val) {
    var myLatLon = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(val.latitute), parseFloat(val.longtute));
    heatArr[markerCount] = {location: myLatLon, weight: 2};
    heatMapBounds.extend(myLatLon);
    markerCount++;
});

var sheatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data:new google.maps.MVCArray(heatArr),
    radius:30
});
sheatmap.setMap(map);
map.fitBounds(heatMapBounds);
bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(null);
```

And data getting in marker_points

```
 [
 Object { latitute="33.65112310998252",  longtute="-117.98994390000001"},
 Object { latitute="33.650867",  longtute="-117.990379"}, 
 Object { latitute="33.650867",  longtute="-117.990379"}, 
 Object { latitute="33.650855606216076",  longtute="-117.99054136256564"}, 
 Object { latitute="33.650867",  longtute="-117.990379"}, 
 Object { latitute="33.651302292183665",  longtute="-117.99096972341766"}, 
 Object { latitute="33.65106477008209",  longtute="-117.99117056945039"}
 ......
]
```

anyone please help me to show heatmap correct datapoints ?

Comment: What does the data look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue **in the question itself** (if possible).

Comment: Yes it sounds more likely to be a problem with the data supplied for `marker_points` than the number of points

Comment: @ducan data is supplied proper using ajax for different date ranges.I can see in firebug console. Each time when coordinates increases data on heatmap decreases.

Comment: relation between no. of coordinates and datapoints on heatmap is inverse.  As more coordinates represent less data on heatmap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

dissipating:true and maxIntensity:10 fixed my problem. Thank you everyone helping.

Answer (score 0):

In case others with a larger scale might encounter this, I had a similar case with the following features:

1. Had around 30K Points
2. Over a large country like Mexico.

dissipating:true, maxIntensity:1 , radius: 10

AND:
I added a weight of 2 to each point. (You can do that with Google Heatmap)